# How to use the squeeze lemma to prove a sequence converges and its limit?

Tags: real-analysis

I am solving the following problem.

Let $a_n = (n-\sin(n))/n$.

Now, using the squeeze lemma I am to show that $a_n$ converges and find it's limit.

I understand the squeeze lemma as a lemma that says the single limit of two sequences are equivalent implying the equivalence of another sequences limit (e.g., $\lim a_n = \lim c_n = \lim b_n$).

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate, although I'm too lazy right now to find it.

Comment: I looked and couldn't find a duplicate. if you could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it

Comment: You don't understand mathcounterexamples.net's answer? You're taking the limit as $x$ approaches infinity. So think about what happens for large $n$ and formalise it in terms of previously known theorems/facts.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you haven't told us what the "squeeze lemma" is exactly. Please write this as a formal theorem/lemma and then we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$-1 \le \sin n \le 1$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.